# c api expects char* memory (malloc) and how to avoid this malloc. Code refactoring

Tags: c++, c, refactoring

I have a c library API that expects something similar to below,
(I am doing refactoring on the old C++ code)

```
some c++ program.cpp which uses that clibrary:

char *getname = (char*)malloc(20);
getMeName(20, getname); //the c api
cout<<getname; //some operations wit the red data
free(getname);
```

the C API declaration:

```
int getMeName(int maxNumberCharacters, char *array);
```

the test examples to this C API is similar to the above code.

How to avoid the malloc() here and What is the best clean way to do it.

Comment: How have you determined that the API expects malloc? You may be mistaken.

Comment: Are you sure `getName` requires you to allocate the string with `malloc`?  Typically that's not the case if you are passing into a function an already allocated string to get data populated.  Typically you'll get a function that returns a string that was allocated with `malloc` and you'll need to `free` it.

Comment: The function probably just needs a pointer to the data (or in other way, the address of the data), which can be allocated with malloc, but it can be from anywhere. Just take the address of the data with `&`.

Comment: the only case the C API could force you to write such code I can imagine is when it first calls `free` and then `malloc` on the pointer you pass it, and I doubt thats really the case. Please explain why you think you need to write such code in C++

Comment: Can you describe what *exactly* the `getMeName` does? Maybe you have the source code of `getMeName`, then have a look at it and/or share it with us.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - Don't be so sure. It's not uncommon for C API's to accept a pointer to an initial buffer (or NULL), `realloc` it if space is not sufficient, and return a pointer to the memory they wrote into. That behavior has to be documented however.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica ... but how would a `realloc` be possible with `getMeName(20, getname);`?

Comment: `std::string getname(20, '\0'); getMeName(20, getname.data()); auto p = getname.find('\0'); getname.resize(p == std::string::npos ? getname.size() - 1 : p);` would be an option. If `getMeName()` returns the length it would be even easier.

Comment: Unless it returns a `char*`, `realloc` is not happening inside `getMeName`

Comment: With the prototype `int getMeName(int maxNumberCharacters, char *array)` it is very unlikely that `array` is expected to point to a buffer specifically allocated with `malloc`. Most likely `array` is just required to point to any buffer of a length of `maxNumberCharacters`. But it's __your__ job to tell us what exactly `getMeName` does. Do your have any documentation of the C API?

Comment: Is the `int` it returns the length of the data it put in `array`? Can it return a negative value?

Comment: It's a very strange API if `char getname[20]; getMeName(20, getname);` is not supposed to work equally well. If that *is* supposed to work, that's a very bad example.

Comment: Another point about representing the problem reliably: If this is indeed the code you are looking at, `malloc(fixed_small_size); manipulate_without_realloc; free` - all in one scope - then you are looking at something Jonathon's answer addresses most cleanly (with a standard deviation of one `std::array`). If the allocated size is dynamic, or the memory is meant to be hoisted out of the scope this is in, then it's a different ball game. So, [mre]?

Comment: Please, at least, describe what the returned `int` in `int getMeName(...);` is and what possible values it may hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you want to allocate the string buffer directly on the stack, you could use:

```
char getname[20];
getMeName(20, getname);
cout<<getname;
```

In this case the memory will be allocated on the stack and identifier `getname` will be a pointer to the contents.

I would assume that API `getMeName` will include a Null terminator `'\0'` at the end of the string at or before element 19.  This also assumes that the API does not require the buffer to be dynamically allocated.

Comment: also if the requirements are as stated in the question then this wont meet them (though it is rather unclear waht the actual requirements are). In other words: This might be ok or it might be not, we cannot know

Answer (score 0):

> c api expects char* malloc and how to avoid malloc

If the API expects malloc, then you can avoid malloc by not using that API. You can for example design and implement a new API.

Well designed C API's rarely have expectations about where the memory is from. Even though such API may be used with malloc, that doesn't mean that you would have to use malloc on C++. The documentation of the API should mention if malloc is expected. The function declaration is not sufficient to determine that.

If the API just requires pointer to any writeable memory, then you can use it as if the API was written in pure C++. I recommend using whatever memory is appropriate for the use case.

Comment: The question does not mention that the API expects `malloc`.  I would assume its just looking for a pointer and buffer length to avoid overflow.

Comment: @JonathonS. I've literally quoted the question that mentions API that expects malloc.

Comment: @eerorika,  Jonathon S. is correct. It does not expect a malloc but a pointer to fill the data. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @eerorika  I guess I am reading it differently.  It says "I have a c library API that expects something similar to below" then later asks if there is a way to do the same thing without needing to use `malloc`.  I am just assuming that if it requires the user to input a pointer and a length, that it is basically just going to fill the buffer.

Comment: absolutely correct  Jonathon S. Thanks for reframing.

Comment: @JonathonS. That's a reasonable assumption, but it's not guaranteed. One has to know what the function does exactly, or at least know its documentation to know whether it requires malloc or not. As I stated in the answer, requiring malloc is indeed rare. But it's not a non-existent requirement.